# Prove that every complex number is in the range of the entire function $e^{3z} + e^{2z}.$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove that every complex number is in the range of the entire function $e^{3z} + e^{2z}.$

By Picard we have that every number except maybe one is, but that is all I've got.  Help would be great!  Thanks.

Comment: it is just $w^3 + w^2,$ with $w = e^z,$ the only restriction is $w \neq 0.$